# Proof that $\frac {(2n)!}{n! 2^n}$ is integer

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

I need to prove in a **Combinatoric way** that:
$$\frac {(2n)!}{n! 2^n}$$
is an integer for all natural $n$.

Actually I have no idea where to start from.
Thank all.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to format your questions from now onwards(check my edit), and also include your own attempts.

Comment: See perhaps also [Find the total number of matchings in a complete graph with even number of vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375051)